# R's new native pipe does not work How to solve?

Tags: r, tidyverse, pipe, magrittr

This is my reproducible sample data

```
df1 <- structure(list(No = 1:3, A = c(1L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 1L, 0L),
                      C = c(1L, 2L, 1L), D = c(0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(No = 1:3, A = c(1L, 0L, 2L), B = c(0L, 1L, 1L), E = c(1L, 2L, 1L), 
                      F = c(1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I want to merge these two `dfs` and then compute the sum of each column while `group_by` the `No` column.

With the old native pipe, it worked well.

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(No) %>%
  summarise(across(colnames(.)[-1], sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop")

# A tibble: 3 x 7
     No     A     B     C     D     E     F
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     0     1     0     1     1
2     2     0     2     2     1     2     1
3     3     2     1     1     0     1     0
```

However, if I use the new native pipe `|>`, I got this error

```
Error in `summarise()`:
i In argument: `across(colnames(.)[-1], sum, na.rm = TRUE)`.
i In group 1: `No = 1`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while evaluating `colnames(.)[-1]`.
Caused by error in `is.data.frame()`:
! object '.' not found
```

I realized that there are some limitations using the new native pipe. Any suggestions for this case?

Comment: @jpsmith I tried this link but still could not find the solution.

Comment: oh thanks it worked @BenBolker. I tried to exclude `No` column, but seem I am `grouping_by` it so could not call it out. Silly me! Regarding the placeholder, I followed the same link above but it is so weird :((( could not get the solution if I stick using `colnames` function. But thanks anw

Comment: For this particular case  (and with up to date `dplyr` ) it would be `bind_rows(df1, df2) |> summarise(across(everything(), \(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)), .by = No)` .

Comment: @margusl, you're right. (Although I personally prefer `~ ...` syntax to the `\(x)` anonymous function)

Comment: @BenBolker you meant prefer using `...` in general, or in my case here. Could you tell a bit hint why? since 3 dots also confused me :)))

Comment: I mean that **purely on stylistic grounds** I prefer e.g. `~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE)` over `\(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` (my guess is that the latter is marginally more robust, although I don't know any cases where they would behave differently - maybe where there's potential confusion over the `.` placeholder?)

Comment: ah ok, it is clear now. I was confused `. . .` being an agrument here but turned out it refers the part behind :D. Thanks alot.